# Опечатки на странице объединения учётных записей

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На [странице связи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) при выборе пункта «объединение учётных записей» присутствуют опечатки.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уётные записти требуют внимания.

Comment: Улётные записи. Кто-то high)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, поправил перевод в Transifex. Он, как это уже стало ожидаемым, был слетевший и использовался из локального кэша.

После череды обновлений должно появиться на сайте.